# Are there any attacks / weak points with HMAC-SHA3?

Tags: cryptanalysis, authentication

I read about SHA3 and would like to study its weak point,
Are there any cryptographic attacks on SHA3-based HMAC?

Answer (score 2):

No. Any such attack is yet to be discovered and would constitute a publishable result.

Answer (score 2):

There are many attacks on Keccak:

- https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-34047-5_23
- https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-34047-5_25
- ...

None of them are even close to actually breaking it in a practical way and they only apply to plain Keccak but the HMAC construction is known to be very resilient. Specifically HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-MD5 seem to remain secure although neither MD5 nor SHA1 are.

Comment: None of them are close to breaking it even *theoretically*. They attack reduced round variants.